# Does a Peltier device conduct heat when turned off?

Tags: heat-transfer, thermocouple

If I put a Peltier device between a heat source and a heat sink (Peltier turned off),
How well will it conduct heat? as opposed to lets say a copper block?

Thank you

Comment: Everything conducts heat.  It's a matter of how much.  In my experience thermal resistance tends to be higher than ceramic of equivalent thickness.  You can usually model it and with temp sensors figure the equivalent properties to fit the model to what you measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most thermometric cooling modules (Peltier devices) are made out of [Bismuth Telluride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth_telluride) which has a thermal conductivity of 1.20 W/(m·K), similar to ordinary glass.

From this wiki [list of thermal conductivities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_thermal_conductivities): 
Copper, 401 W/(m·K)
Aluminum, 237 W/(m·K)

So for a given temperature differential, a thermometric cooling module in the off state would conduct 334 times less heat than copper and 197 times less heat than aluminum.

Comment: I'd expect some dependency of  the thermal conductivity with the electrical load on the Peltier. See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/286479753_Load-Bearing_Figure-of-Merit_Characterization_of_a_Thermoelectric_Module

Comment: @DDuck what electrical load? The OP makes it clear it is off...

Comment: You also have to figure in the contribution or the two ceramic layers, but otherwise a good answer.

Comment: @SolarMike If the Peltier leads are shorted, is it off? Or is it off when they're open circuit?

Comment: @DDuck OP wrote “(peltier turned off)”, so you need to clarify with OP...